# Does Material UI auto-upgrade every time a new version is released? When should I upgrade it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a React website using Material UI. I am concerned that the components I use will become deprecated over time.

Quick clarification: Does Material UI auto-upgrade every time a new version is released? I read that packages only upgrade when `npm upgrade` is run, but I just wanted to confirm that it is fine as long as I specify the MUI package version in package.json file, even after I run `npm build`. I understand that the packages are not included in the final build folder.

Question on best practice: When should I upgrade it? As there are too many components that I'm using in my React app and I can't comb through my code every time there's an update, should I avoid upgrading Material UI in my app until there's a major refresh, e.g. from v5 to v6 and clean up my code at one shot?

Comment: Assuming that the authors of MUI follow the principles of [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), you should be safe to perform patch (x.y.1 to x.y.2) or minor (x.5.z to x.6.0) version bumps. Check your package.json to see how you lock your versions in: https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#using-semantic-versioning-to-specify-update-types-your-package-can-accept. However all these are based on assumptions that the third party vendor follows versioning rules correctly (chances are, MUI will).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `github`, you can setting up `dependabot` to your `repository`.

`dependabot` checking depencency of your project frequently. If some package has updated, `dependabot` will PR to your repository. Just check the changelog and merge.

[dependabot](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-security-updates/configuring-dependabot-security-updates)